# Alarm is silent because "Unable to play during call" because of facebook messenger

Tags: alarm, samsung-galaxy-s-9, facebook-messenger

This morning, the alarm did not wake me up.
When I change the ringtone, I cannot hear how the new ringtone sounds (the phone is still silent) but I get the message

> Unable to play during call

My conclusion is that the phone did not sound when the alarm went off earlier this morning because the phone was "in a call".

An alarm should not be blocked by anything (and there was no call).

How do I fix it?

I closed apps one after another and when I had closed facebook messenger, I could hear ringtones again.

But as long as the phone thinks running a particular app makes it being "in a call" and as long as being in a call blocks the alarm sound, the question remains.

[image: phone after trying to change alarm and make it play the new one]

Comment: User [Pmx](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) app, grant it [permission over adb](https://t.me/PermissionManagerX/4) and deny all permissions of that app related to `CALL`// That also means don't use that app for calling